# j2ee.jar in jboss 6.0 as

Tags: jakarta-ee

i install jboss 6.0 in mac os

i could not find j2ee.jar in JBOSS/client directory.

where can i found j2ee.jar? i have check some of links. it mentions j2ee.jar locate in JBOSS/client but it jboss 4.0 version.